# const enum or number union in typescript type definition file

Tags: typescript, enums, union-types

I maintain an NPM package, in which the values of some attributes may be some fixed numbers, and each number represents a certain meaning (for historical reasons, these values are not designed as strings with specific meanings, but meaningless numbers, just like `Node.NodeType` in HTML, which I will use as an example later).

In the beginning, it was defined as number, but it was too vague.

```js
interace Node {
  /**
   *  type of this node, can only be 1 or 3 or 4 as example
   */ 
  nodeType: number;
}

const node = {nodeType : 5} // You can still set 5, even if it's not right
```

So it was later changed to number Union, but the meaning of each number still can't be reflected when writing code, and it can only be explained by force in comments

```js
/**
 * Possible node type values
 * 
 * + 1: element node
 * + 3: text node
 * + 4: cdata section
 */ 
type INodeType = 1 | 3 | 4;

interface Node {
  /**
   * type of this node
   */  
  nodeType: INodeType
}

const node = {nodeType : 5} // error

const node = {nodeType : 4} // no error, however it's hard to quickly know what 4 means
```

So later I use enum to avoid the problem of ambiguity. At the same time, I can add comments to each enum member, which will be recognized by typedoc and generate useful documents.

```js
/**
 * Possible node type values
 */ 
enum NODE_TYPE = {
  /**
   * element node
   */  
  ELEMENT = 1,
  /**
   * text node
   */  
  TEXT = 3,
  /**
   * cdata section
   */  
  CDATA = 4
}

interface Node {
  /**
   * type of this node
   */  
  nodeType: NODE_TYPE
}

const node = {nodeType : 5} // error

const node = {nodeType : NODE_TYPE.CDATA} // no error, and can quickly know what means
```

Later, I need to put these enum definitions in the package's type definition file index.d.ts, so that users of the package can get type information from it. However, enum cannot be put in the type definition file, so I changed it to const enum, which can also be used, except that the compiled enum usage will be changed to inline number,

```js
/**
 * Possible node type values
 */ 
const enum NODE_TYPE = {
  /**
   * element node
   */  
  ELEMENT = 1,
  /**
   * text node
   */  
  TEXT = 3,
  /**
   * cdata section
   */  
  CDATA = 4
}

interface Node {
  /**
   * type of this node
   */  
  nodeType: NODE_TYPE
}

const node = {nodeType : 5} // error

const node = {nodeType : NODE_TYPE.CDATA} // no error, will be compiled to var node = {nodeType: 4 /** CDATA **/}
```

However, some projects using this package are compiled in the mode of `--isolatedmodules` which will ignore const enum. As a result, the const enum used in these projects is not replaced with the inline number, and there will be errors when running.

So I can only return to number Union, so that I can't know the meaning of each number. At the same time, there is no explanation and comment for each number in the generated typedoc document. [There is a proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/tsdoc/issues/164) to comment on each element of union enum like:

```js
/**
 * Possible node type values
 */ 
type INodeType = 
  /**
   * element node
   */  
  | 1,
  /**
   * text node
   */  
  | 3,
  /**
   * cdata section
   */  
  | 4
}
```

and it seems that there is no progress so far.

I don't know if there are any friends who have the same experience as me. Do you have any better ideas

Comment: Do you want to override Node global interface?

Comment: You can define some constants to be these numeric values and comments on the constants.